# Check which processes are eating swap on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, shell, swap, memory-management

To see some memory info I can watch it in `top` of through `cat /proc/meminfo`.
In /proc/meminfo I can see the swap usage of the whole system like this:

```
SwapCached:            4 kB
SwapTotal:      33460220 kB
SwapFree:       33460216 kB
```

But there can be I situation when almost all the swap is used (i.e. there is a too small piece of `SwapFree`). How can I figure out, which process(es) are eating this swap?

UPD: there is a too small piece of `SwapFree` basically means that there is some process(processes) which ate a lot of memory and didn't use it for a long time. I need to find such processes.

Comment: @Peregrino69 If something gets swapped it means that it eats a lot of memory and is not under use. I.e. these memory pages are rarely used

Comment: @Peregrino69 Nope. The question is what **processes** are eating swap. I need to find all the processes that ate memory a lot and didn't use it for long time, so they were swapped.
If process is eating memory eagerly and uses it quite often - I'm not interested in that.

Comment: @Peregrino69 why not as answer?

Comment: @Peregrino69 `press 'p' to add swap to display` when I go to SWAP: ` SWAP    = Swapped Size (KiB)` and press `p` nothing happens..

Comment: Now that works, at least to the point of displaying swap - can't vouch further as my swap utilization is zero. Thanks for kicking my butt :-) I'm dropping a comment on the thread I quoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Run `top`
2. Press `f` to select displayed fields
3. Navigate down to SWAP using arrow keys
4. Hit `Space` - SWAP will become preceded by asterisk `*`
5. Press right arrow key - this will allow you to move SWAP to a convenient place in the listing, for example between %MEM and TIME+
6. Press q to return to top view

Step  5 isn't necessary, just convenience - without it SWAP will be showing up as the last entry of the list, after `COMMAND`.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I see, which processes ate more swap? Should I sort?

Comment: *"without it SWAP will be showing up as the last entry of the list, after COMMAND"* - nope, it will not show after COMMAND column in my case.

Comment: The testing comes from my system (BunsenLabs / Debian 10) which runs a version of top, I can't be certain whether your system has the same version, so can't confirm whether step 5 is needed there. By default top in my system sorts on CPU utilization, so you need to use either option `-o` when launching it, or choose the column used for sorting with command `s` in the field view (`f`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `smem` command line tool.

[smem manpages:](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/smem/smem.8.en.html)

```
Memory can be reported by process, by user, by mapping,
or systemwide. Both text mode and graphical output are available.
```

[smem memory reporting tool](https://www.selenic.com/smem/)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this tool, but the webpage doesn't mention swap. Judging by the output it only shows RAM or combined RAM or swap, which isn't useful in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately this tool is not a regular utility in Linux. So it most likely that there is no such tool in random server/machine. It is not always possible to download anything from anywhere

Answer (score 1):

A tool for monitoring memory and swap usage is smemstat, what can show top-like output with

`smemstat -mT`
(  "Swap reports memory that is swapped out to disk." [man smemstat](http://manpages.org/smemstat/8) )

in terminal, sorted for highest memory usage on top.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to sort processes by swap?

Comment: **[1]** `smemstat -m | sort -n -k 2` or reverse `smemstat -m | sort -nr -k 2` should sort for amount of swap used, **[2]** customizing a script https://superuser.com/a/355710/981508 for more diverse tasks